# How to find a particular link in a table which is repeating using a particular text in a column using xpath

Tags: xpath

I have table like below without any id.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Delete</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td><a><i class="btn red">close</i> </a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
   <td><a><i class="btn red">close</i> </a></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>ABC Products</td>
    <td>Menu Perrita</td>
   <td><a><i class="btn red">close</i> </a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I need to click on the Close (X) button of the 2nd row. Which is in Centro comercial Moctezuma. This row is not display at 2nd always. It can be at any place. But I need to click on the particular Close button to delete the mentioned row for a selenium test.

Please help me in writing the xpath to identify the particular button.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the following XPath

//td[text()='Centro comercial Moctezuma']/following-sibling::/td//i[text()='close']

Comment: Thanks. I did something similar to this.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
//tr[td = 'Centro comercial Moctezuma']/td/a
```